# CodeIgniter routes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I found out that my routes are not working at all, when I type in the route it says 'Object not found'. It loads the index function by default and that works , but the routes won't.

routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'personeelcontroller';
$route['personeelcontroller/editPersoon'] = 'maincontroller/editPersoon';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['personeelcontroller/onInit'] = 'personeelcontroller/onInit';
$route['personeelcontroller/index'] = 'personeelcontroller/index';
```

controller:

```
class PersoneelController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('PersoneelModel');
        $this->load->model('ProjectModel');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['personeel'] = $this->PersoneelModel->getPersonen();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('urls/home' , $data);
    }

    public function onInit()
    {
        $data['projecten'] = $this->ProjectModel->GetProjecten();
        $this->load->view('urls/projects' , $data);// laad deze view wanneer methode wordt opgeroepen
    }

    public function editPersoon(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'Id', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('urls/failed');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->PersoneelModel->editPersoon();
            $this::index();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Note: Your naming your classes wrong read here* http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Routes like `$route['default_controller'] = 'personeelcontroller';`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. If that was wrong it would not have executed the index method that returns a view. @wolfgang1983

Comment: Still read the link I gave you for correct way of classes and file names

Answer (score 1):

check if there is any .htaccess file in root. if not add the .htaccess file 
and write the following code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```